# How can I add DOM support with JSDOM to use functions like document.getElementById() when using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, jsdom

Ello!

I am looking to change apart of my inner html using `document.getElementById("textToChange").innerHTML`.

However, I keep getting this error when I attempt to run my JS file with `node filename.js`

> TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')
> at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\Luke.Gebbink\Documents\wallboardgit\JS\sslCert.js:44:58)
> at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
> at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)

I am assuming that the JSDOM global.document is not the actual webpage. How can I make it so that I can run code that refers to my index.html's elements using JSDOM; as it will not without it. Here is my code below.

```
    const jsdom = require("jsdom");
        const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
        
        const dom = new JSDOM(`<!DOCTYPE html><p>Hello world</p>`);
 global.document = new JSDOM().window.document;

        console.log(dom.window.document.querySelector("p").textContent); // "This Runs, so I have JSDOM Installed"

        document.getElementById("textToChange").innerHTML = 'TEST' //This does not work
```

Comment: You do not have any `#textToChange` element (nor does it look like you've defined `document` - also, you should have an `<html>` tag and a `<body>` tag before a `<p>`)

Comment: The html is in an external file. I have #textToChange element in there. I am confused on to where I connect JSDOM to my index.html file , so it can see the element I am looking to change.

Comment: Read the file's text so you can pass it to JSDOM

Comment: I forgot to add the global line from my JS file. What do you mean read the files text? I am a bit confused on how to start using JSDom to do this task. are you saying the 'const dom' is where I need to put it?

Comment: `new JSDOM()` is not passing anything into JSDOM... you have to pass in the string

Comment: So do I just copy the whole page into there? Or do I put the file path? Sorry for the questions; I just discovered this library today.

Comment: https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom#fromurl